# How to merge this two if-else statement in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
can_go(Place) :- here(X), connect(X, Place).
can_go(Place) :- ('You cannnot get there from here'), nl,
fail.
can_go(location(treasure,room)) :- location(key,in_hand).
can_go(location(treasure,room)) :- write('cannot enter here without keys'), nl,
fail.
```

Comment: it's not entirely clear what you want. Could you express your "if else" problem in pseudocode?

Answer (score 0):

There are two distinct concepts involved here: Whether you can physically get from one place to another, and whether you are *allowed* to get from one place to another. In general, you should have different predicates for different concepts. Physical reachability is modeled in part by your `connect/2` predicate, but let's make it more explicit:

```
reachable(Place) :-
    here(X),
    connect(X, Place).
```

Then, let's rename the other part of your definition to `allowed_to_go/1`:

```
allowed_to_go(location(treasure,room)) :-
    location(key,in_hand).
allowed_to_go(location(treasure,room)) :-
    write('cannot enter here without keys'), nl,
    fail.
```

Now, you *can* go some place if that place is reachable, *and* you are allowed to go there. The conjunction ("and") is simply the comma (`,`):

```
can_go(Place) :-
    reachable(Place),
    allowed_to_go(Place).
can_go(Place) :-
    write('You cannnot get there from here'), nl,
    fail.
```

A problem that remains is that if a place is reachable but you are not allowed to go there, you will print two error messages, one of which is irrelevant. There are several ways to solve this. Some would probably suggest adding a cut (`!`), but you should avoid that if there are simpler, clearer choices. In this particular case, negation might be the simplest possibility. You will not get the spurious error if you add a guard to the second clause of `can_go/1`:

```
can_go(Place) :-
    \+ reachable(Place),
    write('You cannnot get there from here'), nl,
    fail.
```

Another way would be to use the if-then-else operator (`->`). (Note: I didn't test any of this.)